# Syntax Highlighting in Hugo with blogdown in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'm using `blogdown` and the [`lxndrblz/anatole`](https://github.com/lxndrblz/anatole) theme to create a blog.
The blog should have usual syntax highlighting, which should be supported.

When I create a new post in markdown (not Rmarkdown!) like the following, it works as expected.

Eg `index.md` (not Rmd!)

````
---
author: Someone
date: "sometime"
title: Something
---

```R
library(tidyverse)
  starwars %>%
  select(name, mass)
```
````

Resulting in this version in the blog:

[image]

When I use the same content in Rmarkdown (not even an evaluated code chunk), there is no syntax highlighting.

Eg `index.Rmd`

````
---
author: Someone
date: "sometime"
title: Something
---

```R
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>%
  select(name, mass)
```
````

returns

[image]

When I look at the output of the knitted document of `index.Rmd` I see that it is a `.html` file with this content:

```html
---
title: Something
author: Someone
date: Sometime
---

<script src="{{< blogdown/postref >}}index_files/header-attrs/header-attrs.js"></script>
<div id="something-r" class="section level1">

<h1>Something R</h1>
<pre class="r"><code>library(tidyverse)
  starwars %&gt;%
select(name, mass)</code></pre>
</div>
```

whereas the earlier, syntax highlighted markdown will be translated into this (taken from inspecting the html code of the blog):

```html
<pre tabindex="0" class="chroma">
  <code class="language-R" data-lang="R">
    <span class="nf">library</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="n">tidyverse</span><span class="p">)</span>
    <span class="n">starwars</span> <span class="o">%&gt;%</span>
    <span class="nf">select</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="n">name</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="n">mass</span><span class="p">)</span>
  </code>
</pre>
```

### Question

Now my question is this:
is there a yaml-`output` mode that preserves the yaml-headers but does its magic on the chunks in the right format (note the appendix below)? With this, knitting the chunks would turn the "wrong" `index.Rmd` to an accurate `index.md` which is then picked up and formatted by Hugo. (Using `output: md_document` leads to the removal of the yaml-headers.)

### Alternative?

Alternatively, at the moment I use the following `config.yaml` to enable syntax highlighting.

```yaml
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: yes
  highlight:
    anchorLineNos: true
    codeFences: true
    guessSyntax: true
    hl_Lines: ""
    lineAnchors: ""
    lineNoStart: 1
    lineNos: true
    lineNumbersInTable: true
    noClasses: true
    style: monokai
    tabWidth: 4
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

### Appendix

I have tried to set to preseve the yaml and knit to .md like so

```
output: 
  md_document:
    preserve_yaml: true
```

but the output code is indented and not kept in the backticks and is not highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let `.Rmd` generate `.md` output instead of the default `.html` by setting `options(blogdown.method = 'markdown')` in your `.Rprofile`. See [this section in the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html).

Then restart R, delete `index.html`, and serve the site again.

Comment: In case anyone else struggled as I did, `usethis::edit_r_profile(scope = "project")` helped me